# Sufficient condition for convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Given a function $f\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and that
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{-t}^tf(x) \ dx=1,
$$
does the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \ dx
$$
necessarily converge? I've been trying to come up with a counterexample rather than a proof, but to no avail yet.

Comment: Can you construct a counterexample when we swap $1$ for $0$? Is there anything meaningfully different between these examples? Recall we can't have $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: Try $C \sin x / x$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: The identity function is the easiest counterexample in that case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any integrable function $g$ with compact support such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dx = 1$. Then take some function integrable on compact intervals with $h(-x) = -h(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ but which is not integrable. Define $f := h + g$. For large $t > 0$ it holds $\int_{-t}^t f(x) dx = 1$, so $\lim_{t\to \infty}\int_{-t}^t f(x) dx = 1$, but since $h$ is not integrable and $g$ is, $f$ is not integrable. So, for example $g(x) = 1$ for $|x|\leq 1/2$ and $g(x) = 0$ for $|x|>1/2$ and $h(x) = x$.

Comment: But in your example $\int_{\mathbb R}g(x)\ dx=\int_{\mathbb R}x\ dx \neq 1$? Or did you mean to swap $h$ and $g$?